# while shifting from log4j to SLF4j using the SLF4J Migrator how to replace the log4j.xml with the logback.xml

Tags: log4j, slf4j, logback

I am switching from log4j to SLF4j. I used SLF4J Migrator for this. Now is it possible to use logback.xml instead of the log4j.xml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

log4j.xml and logback.xml are quite similar so you should be able to convert to the latter format manually with relative ease. If you find it difficult, please send a message on the logback user mailing  list and we'll work through it together.